# Comcast Speed test slower performance on the IPv4 test than on the IPv6 Test

Tags: ipv6, ipv4

I have two computers. On one I get the same performance result for both IPv4 and IPv6. On the other I get slower (about 50%) on IPv4 than on IPv6. Why? Is there a config to change it?

Comment: Slower up? Slower down? Both? What operating system? What actual speed numbers did you get? Were all the tests to the same server?

Comment: Both Win7. One one I get 57mbs for both IPv4 and 6. On the other I get about 20mbs on IPv4 and 57mbs in IPv6..

Comment: I'm using the Comcast speed test to the same server in Naples Fl...

Comment: Have you run multiple tests with the same results?

Comment: Originally I was getting the same result on both computers (slow in IPv4, fast on IPv6). Then for some reason the one started showing the same result for both while the other computer still shows IPv4 slower.

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that this is some sort of error with bandwidth capping.

As you know, you pay Comcast for a specific level of bandwidth (16Mbits/s, 25Mbits/s, whatever). My guess is that they are applying the limits to IPv4 traffic, but not to IPv6 traffic. Since this limit is actually enforced by the cable modem, there may be some issue with your specific device causing the limit to not be applied correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the Comcast's ill-configured network, which marks all packets as low priority which causes confusion with your routers WMM protocol. [See my answer here](https://superuser.com/questions/828196/throttled-download-speeds-on-new-router-ipv6-vs-ipv4) along with the link for a detailed description of the problem.

The easy solution involves disabling WMM in your router's settings.