# IPv6 : Access comcast delegated 2601 /64 internal network over the internet

Tags: networking, routing, ipv6

I'm trying to understand how IPv6 networks work.

I have been assigned a 2001: /128 address by Comcast (my ISP) for my internet facing cable modem (c300-100NAS Netgear).

I have received a system delegated prefix of 2601:243:1501:xxxx::/60 and a LAN deligated prefix for my internal network 2601:243:1501:xxxx::/64

This automatically assigned IP address of 2601:: /64 network to all devices in my internal network at home. I can even connect to each other using these IP addresses. But when i access these from the internet, i am not able to reach them. I think i am missing the routes for the 2601 /64 networks that lead into my home. (these are acting similar to ipv4 private addresses)

**Q1: what is the difference between system and LAN deligated prefixes**

**Q2: What should i do to be able to access my machines over the internet using 2601::/64 address. I am typically looking to use ssh and http ports.**

Thanks for your help in advance.

**Extra information:**

1. Internet browsing over ipv6 works.
2. My internal machines (ubuntu linux) both pass the ipv6 tests.
3. what is my ipv6 displays my 2601::/64 ip address.
4. Both machines can talk to each other over ipv6 but only internally behind the router.

Comment: You *did* configure the firewall on your router/modem, right? It’ll hopefully block traffic like IPv4 NAT by default.

Comment: I'm still figuring this out. I want ipv4 NAT to still be enabled. IPv6 is only to allow access certain machines over their standard ports. For example i want some users to be able to directly ssh to two machines in the internal network as i have only one public ip and cant forward traffic  from one port to multiple hosts.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Throttled download speeds on new router with Comcast (ipv6 vs ipv4)](http://superuser.com/questions/828196/throttled-download-speeds-on-new-router-with-comcast-ipv6-vs-ipv4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind. I was trying to reach my network from a machine that did not have ipv6 enabled.